# How to instrument the modification of register sp in valgrind

Tags: valgrind

I want to track the modification of the x86_64 stack register (sp) by writing a simple valgrind tool. Is there some other tool that tracks modification of sp (or other register modifications) already where I could peek and copy from? I guess that I need to parse the `IRStmt` tagged `Ist_Put` and look for `Put.offset == offset_SP`. Are there tools that already do that? I want to print out the values that are written to SP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See pub_tool_tooliface.h.
This defines a bunch of 'void VG_(track_new_mem_stack*) functions
and  VG_(track_die_mem_stack*) functions to track changes to SP.

Unless you need very high performance tracking (such as needed by memcheck),
it should be good enough to use :

- VG_(track_new_mem_stack)
- VG_(track_new_mem_stack_signal)
- VG_(track_die_mem_stack)
- VG_(track_die_mem_stack_signal)